# SQL JOIN return record from table flights corresponding form table 2

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I want list all flights in flights table where Departure and arrival is egal to table 2.
The specificity is that the Departure in flight is XXXX -dsdjqlkdjlqs or XXXXdkjfhkds etc... and in table 2 is only XXXX

Code :

```
    CREATE TABLE flights
    (`Name` varchar(10), `Departure` varchar(50), `Arrival` varchar(10), `Pass` int, `Cargo` int, `Dist` int)
;

INSERT INTO flights
    (`Name`, `Departure`, `Arrival`, `Pass`, `Cargo`, `Dist`)
VALUES
    ('444 737vvv', 'LFLL gee', 'LPMAdsf', 200, 2000, 12),
    ('gg737vvv', 'LPMA-egege', 'LFLLdsf', 3000, 0, 13),
    ('747vvv', 'LFLLèèegege', 'LPMAdsf', 0, 5000, 15),
    ('747vvv', 'OTHHèèegege', 'LPMAdsf', 0, 5000, 15),
    ('747vvv', 'OMDBèèegege', 'LPMAdsf', 0, 5000, 15),
    ('a320vvv', 'EGKK-egege', 'LFPOdd', 0, 6000, 14)
;



CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`Dep` varchar(21), `Arri` varchar(21),`Type` varchar(21))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    (`Dep`, `Arri`, `type`)
VALUES
    ('LFLL', 'LFPG', 'cargo'),
    ('LFPG', 'LFLL', 'cargo'),
    ('LFLL', 'LPMA', 'com'),
    ('LPMA', 'LFLL', 'cargo'),
    ('LFPO', 'EGKK', 'cargo'),
    ('EGKK', 'LFPO', 'com')
;
```

I have test :

```
        select flights.name,
       flights.Departure
from flights
where substr(flights.Departure, 1, 4) in (select Dep from table2) and 
substr(flights.Arrival, 1, 4) in (select Arri from table2)
;
```

Example :

I flight from LFLL to LFPG

in table 2 you have the airlines :
LFLL LFPG
LFMT LFPO etc....

With your request, if I flight from LFLL to LFPO the flight appear and it will be not appear because LFLL to LFPO is not an airline.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/026d6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following is what you are looking for:

```
Select
    flights.name,
    flights.Departure
from
    flights
    inner join Table2
        on Table2.Dep = SUBSTRING(flights.Departure,1,4) and Table2.Arri = SUBSTRING(flights.Arrival,1,4)
;
```

You need the SUBSTRING instead of wildcards, since you only want part of the FLIGHTS table entries.  Also, you needed to include the arrival constraint.

Comment: Hello Peter, Now i would join three tables : flights, table2 and vafinance. Table flights and vafinance are linked by ID. I will like you request extract flights where airlines are in tables 2, but from table vafinances. (linked by same ID with table flights)

Comment: I think to :  $query = "Select
 vol.*, flights.*, regular.*
 from
    vol, flights, regular
 where regular.Departure = SUBSTRING(flights.DepartureIcaoName,1,4) 
 and regular.Arrival = SUBSTRING(flights.ArrivalIcaoName,1,4)
 and vol.id = flights.id"
 ;

Comment: Ok work with : $query = "Select
 SUM(beneficev) AS Sbeneficev, flights.*, regular.*
 from
    vol, flights, regular
 where regular.Departure = SUBSTRING(flights.DepartureIcaoName,1,4) 
 and regular.Arrival = SUBSTRING(flights.ArrivalIcaoName,1,4)
 and vol.id = flights.id
 GROUP BY UserName ORDER BY Sbeneficev DESC"
 ;

Comment: Could you help me for this please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983344/sql-previous-next-row

Answer (score 0):

```
select flights.name,
       flights.Departure
from flights
inner join table2
on substr(flights.Departure, 1, 4) = table2.Dep
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `substr` and  `in`:

```
select flights.name,
       flights.Departure
from flights
where substr(flights.Departure, 1, 4) in (select Dep from table2)
```